# How do I put certain elements(String) in Array into a new array(Integer)?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a text file that looks like this

```
4
10 orange
20 grape 
100 Pencil Cases
4 Card
```

The first line is the number of objects. The next lines are the price and the name of the object. I have to find the object with the lowest price and return only the name of the object. (So, in this case "Card")

I put the txt into an Arraylist and split it so I could only get the numbers. I am trying to put the numbers into a new integer array to compare them. And this is the code I've tried.

```
 public class Assignment {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\input.txt"));
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            rd.close();
              for (int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
                String[] items = lines.get(i).split(" ", 2);
                for (String s: items) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                int[] array2 = new int[items.length];  
                int k =0;           
                     for (int n= 2; n< items.length; n=n+2) {
                         array2[k] = Integer.parseInt(items[n]);   
                         for (Integer l: array2) { 
                         System.out.println(l); }
                          }
               }

             }

            catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Error");
              }
     } 
}
```

I think something is wrong with the array2 part. Can someone give a hint on how I should fix this?? New to stackoverflow and Java so I'm sorry if there is a problem with my question(or my grammar too...)!

Comment: Just saying that *something is wrong* won't be helpful. Please tell the exact problem

Comment: Its time to create your own Object which hold name and price ;)

Comment: Why `int n= 2;`?

Comment: @user7 Oh sorry :( From when I print l, nothing comes out from the console.... But I don't get what is wrong with that part.

Comment: @user7 Oh It should be int n =1 but the result didn't come out right so I changed it to 2. You are right It should be int n =1;

Comment: I can see a few ways if you just want the integers alone... you could use regex for one... how much do you know about regex?

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole I only know a little about regex(What it is and basic usage..?). But the professor's intension(this is an assignment) was students to learn how to use arrays and manipulate strings(using indexOf or split) So is there perhaps a way to do in this way?

Comment: yes there is... regex is just shorter... i understand the requirements now

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole It's my fault that I didn't  explain enough!! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to put the numbers into a new integer array to compare them

Here's how you can do it.

```
int[] array2 = new int[lines.size() - 1];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) { //Start at row 1
    String[] items = lines.get(i).split(" ", 2);
    array2[k++] = Integer.parseInt(items[0]); //The first element is the price
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2)); //[10, 20, 100, 4]
```

But, with this, you cannot get the name of the item with the maximum price. So, you need to store both the name and the price together which I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll try this.

Comment: @Jisoo to add on... add under int[] array2 = new int[lines.length - 1]; this:
      String[] products = new String[lines.length - 1];
 and above 
          array2[k++] = Integer.parseInt(items[0]); add
          products[k] = items[1];